# How to get a list of all CouchDB documents that are valid on a given date?

Tags: couchdb

I have a large collection of documents and each is valid for a range of days.  The range could be from 1 week up to 1 year.  I want to be able to get all the documents that are valid on a specific day.

How would I do that?

As an example say I have the following two documents:

```
doc1 = {
  // 1 year ago to today
  start_at: "2012-03-22T00:00:00Z",
  end_at: "2013-03-22T00:00:00Z"
}

doc2 = {
  // 2 months ago to today
  start_at: "2012-01-22T00:00:00Z",
  end_at: "2013-03-22T00:00:00Z"
}
```

And a map function:

```
(doc) ->
  emit([doc.start_at, doc.end_at], null)
```

So for a date of 6 months ago I would only get doc1, a date of 1 week ago I would get both documents, and with a date of tomorrow I would receive no documents.

Note that actual resolution needs to be down to the second of the request being made and there are lots of documents, so strategies of emitting a key for every valid second would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call emit for each day in your range, and then you can easily pick out the documents  available for a specific day.

```
function(doc) {
    var day = new Date(doc.start),
        end = new Date(doc.end).getTime();

    do {
        emit(day);
        day = new Date(day.getFullYear(), day.getMonth(), day.getDate() + 1);
    } while (day.getTime() <= end);
}
```

Even though you will have lots of documents, if you leave out the value part (2nd param) of your emit, the index will be as small as it could possibly be.

If you need to get more sophisticated, you could try out [couchdb-lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene). You can index date fields as date objects and execute range queries with multiple fields in 1 request.

Comment: Getting all the documents that are valid for the given day would probably be a small enough set to handle on the client to then determine which were still valid.  Although on average this would require 180 emits per document...  I would like to avoid adding any additional technology to the stack for just this one problem.

Comment: I would benchmark it at least once to see if you actually run into any problems, I've heard of some pretty big views before.

Comment: Maybe if you use the week number instead, you can use about 1/7th of the disk-space, and maybe use a `_list` function to finish the filter after narrowing down by week.

Comment: I have marked this as the answer, as it is a good solution.  Eventhough I haven't ended up using it.  What I have done is use a view with a map for end times and a list that filters it down to only those with valid start dates as well.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the problem into the computational geometry problem of location. For documents in two dimensional plane `[x,y]=[start_at,end_at]` query for those, which are valid at date `date` is the list of the points in the rectangle bounded by: `left=-infinity, right=date` (`start_at<date`) and `bottom=date, top=infinity` (`end_at>date`).

Unfortunately, CouchDB team underrate the power of computational geometry and does not support multidimensional queries. There is GeoCouch extension that allows you to do this kind of queries as easy as:

```
http://localhost:5984/places/_design/main/_spatial/points?bbox=0,0,180,90
```

on the view emitting spatial value:

```
emit({ type: "Point", coordinates: [doc.start_at, doc.end_at] }, doc);
```

The problem is different data type. You get float in range of `[-180.0,180.0]/[-90.0,90.0]` and need at least `int` (UNIX time format). If GeoCouch works for you in ranges bigger then `180.0` and the precision of float operation designed for geographical calculation is sufficient for dates with precision of seconds your problem is solved :) I am sure, with few tricks and hacks, you could solve this problem efficiently in geo software. If not GeoCouch then perhaps ElastiSearch (also support multidimensional queries) which is easy to use with CouchDB with its River plugins system.

Comment: I would prefer to not introduce additional technology.  The data translation in this case wouldn't really matter as I just need a boolean check on whether or not the document is valid.